# Application.Run(new Form1()); via Command Line Arguments

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, command-line

I'm trying to start an application from command line arguments,

at Normal run, program runs and displays Form1.

I'm looking to start the application with command line arguments to start Form2.

Example: "myapp.exe -form2"

-form2 command line argument should start form2 instead form1.

my program.cs

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Question: Is it possible to show Form2 from command Line argument, like Application.Run(new Form2()); starts Form2.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show your `Main` method please.

Comment: ok, I will Explain..

Comment: the complete method including its signature please. Furthermore post your code to the question, not into the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your 'Main' method in 'Program.cs' to this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    if (args.Contains("-form2"))
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    else
        Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: **Thank you**, it fixed @ivan kishchenko